# Stopping at Southampton on FlyBe: does one stay on the aircraft or is security to be re-cleared?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security

I have an upcoming Jersey-Leeds "direct" flight on FlyBe (BE) with a stop at Southampton (so that's JER-SOU-LBA). Do I need to deplane and re-clear security at Southampton or can I stay onboard the aircraft?

Comment: @Choster Not intentional, I am now so used to them I do indeed think in airline codes. I'll fix that for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was a customs inspection (actually of course no one from customs was there) and so we went through CTA arrivals and back through security before getting on the same bus we just got off.